# catch error and return in method result

Tags: c#, wcf

I have my own wcf service class which should as result return string with "Everything Save Saccesfully" if ok save data. Otherwise I need to return in this string exception.

```
string SaveData(Stream stream)
{
  string error = "";
  try
  {

  //do saving data
   error+="Everything Save Saccefully";
   return error;
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
   throw ex;
  }
  finally
  { 
  }
}
```

It is possible to catch errors occurs in try block and return it in error variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I would do as suggested by Jon, but if you really don't want to allow any exceptions to bubble up from your service you could encapsulate your success and (any) failure error information in a class structure like this

```
public class ErrorInfo
{
    public string Message {get; set;}

    // TODO: Maybe add in other information about the error?
}

public class SaveResult
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set to contain error information if Success = false
    /// </summary>
    public ErrorInfo ErrorInfo { get; set; }
}
```

And then...

```
public SaveResult SaveData(Stream stream)
{
    SaveResult saveResult = new SaveResult();

    string error = "";
    try
    {
        //do saving data
        saveResult.Success = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        saveResult.ErrorInfo = new ErrorInfo { Message = ex.Message };
    }
}
```

The downside of this approach is that your caller must check the `Success` value after calling `SaveData`. Failure to do so can result in a bug in your code that will only manifest itself if the save fails.

Alternatively, if you don't handle the exception you get to benefit from one of the useful things about [structured exception handling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling): If the caller forgets to explicitly handle any exception then it will bubble up the call stack and either crash the app or get caught by some higher-level error handling code.

Not necessarily ideal, but generally better than your code silently assuming that something succeeded, when in fact it didn't.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the traditional way that you express the error *is* simply via an exception - not a return value. Lack of exception should imply "everything went correctly". That's the normal idiomatic way of working.

Now, occasionally it's worth having a method which *doesn't* throw an exception, but instead returns a success status and potentially a separate result via an out parameter. But that's relatively rare - it's usually for things like parsing, where it's entirely normal for it to fail in hard-to-predict ways when nothing's really wrong other than the input data.

In your case, it looks like this should be a `void` method which simply throws an exception on error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
string SaveData(Stream stream) 
{ 
  string error; 
  try 
  { 
  //do saving data 
   error ="Everything saved Successfully"; 
   } 
  catch(Exception ex) 
  { 
   error = ex.Message;
  } 
 return error; 

}
```

Comment: @Baz1nga : sorry, not getting you.

Comment: why bother with setting `error = ""`, and then `+=`ing the success/exception message?

Comment: @RichardEv : True, Actually it's no need of +=, but I have done changes in OP's code and submitted. Now I have changed it.

Comment: @Upendra: If you also remove the `finally` block, you won't then need to initialise the `error` string either.

Comment: @RichardEv : Yes, I have removed it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Faults](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733721.aspx) for exceptional results in WCF. I do not see idea why you would need exception in string. But if you absolutely need this, just move return statement to the end and set its value in catch block too.

```
string SaveData(Stream stream)
{
  string error = "";
  try
  {

  //do saving data
   error+="Everything Save Saccefully";
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
   //throw ex; Do not throw, just return its string representation
   error+=ex.ToString();
  }
  finally
  { 
  }
  return error;
}
```